Question regarding characterization of linearly recurrent subshifts by Durand
I was looking at the following paper by Fabien Durand, Corrigendum and addendum to ‘Linearly recurrent subshifts have a finite number of non-periodic factors’.
I have somewhat of a basic question regarding this paper. The short addendum essentially shows that a subshift is Lineraly-recurrent (LR) if and only if it is a primitive and proper $S$-adic system.
While trying to understand the $S$-adic construction of the Lineraly-recurrent (LR) subshift, I noticed that the if and only if condition should exclude primitive substitutions which are not proper. Clearly a substitutive subshift is $S$-adic with only one morphism to consider. However, it is known that primitive substitutions give rise to LR subshifts.
I assume that a misunderstanding of the statement gives me this contradiction, and I was wondering how to resolve it. Does it mean that any LR subshift has a representation coming from a primitve proper $S$-adic system?

Yes, in general one must apply the return word algorithm in order to find a 'proper' representative. For instance, starting with the substitution $a\mapsto baaa,\ b \mapsto abab$, it is impossible to find a proper substitution which gives the same subshift (and I really mean the same here, not just conugate), because for example the dimension group of a proper two-letter substitution can have rank at most $2$, whereas this substitution has dimension group $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]\oplus \mathbb{Z}^2$, which has rank $3$.
If you only want a subshift which is orbit equivalent, then you can get away with replacing the original substitution with a proper representative substitution by applying the return word algorithm and then composing a sufficiently high power of the resulting substitution (which will be left-proper) with its 'left conjugate' (which will be right-proper) in order to get a two-sided proper substitution. This process is outlined in my paper with Scott Balchin (we don't prove any of the results, just bring them together in order to be easily applied): https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL20/Rust/rust3.html
So, you either lose equality of the subshifts (possibly even conjugacy, I forget), or you have to downgrade the substitutive property to $S$-adic. You can't, in general, have both.

Thanks for the answer. Do you mean the algorithm described on page 25 of your paper? Also, does this mean that one can't realize up to conjugacy any 1-dim LR subshift as a primitive subshift? I thought this what Durand's result implied.

The return word algorithm is the one of several, from the most simple (like the one described on page 25) to more complex, like described in the Durand paper you cite (and they can be even more complex). You were asking specifically about substitutions. It is not true that every subshift coming from a primitive substitution can be realised as a subshift coming from a primitive and proper substitution (I believe this is true even up to conjugacy, but I forget).

If I remember rightly though, there should be a recoding morphism from the 'proper' substitutive subshift to the original (Section 2.3 of my paper here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01246, which uses a very useful result from Durand)

Okay, thanks again.
